# R jsonlite filter records before loading

Tags: json, r, jsonlite, bigdata

I have many large json files (3G each) which I want to load efficiently to a strong RServer machine, however loading all record from all files will be redundant and exhausting (50M records multiply by 40). So I thought using jsonlite package because I heard it's efficient. The thing is that I do not need all records but only a subset of records where an embedded element ("source") have an existing field by the name "duration". 
This is currently my code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(curl)
url <- "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/es-export-data/logstash-2016.02.15.json"
test <- stream_in(url(url))
```

it's only 1 extract of many. now, jsonlite package have a 'flatten' function to flatten embedded elements to create 1 wide flatten data frame. Then I could filter it. However, it seems not efficient. I think that pre-filter it when the data is loaded is much more efficient.
here a dput of one record:

```
> dput(test_data)
"{\"_index\":\"logstash-2016.02.15\",\"_type\":\"productLogs\",\"_id\":\"AVLitaOtp4oNFTVKv9tZ\",\"_score\":0,\"_source\":{\"EntryType\":\"Event\",\"queryType\":\"clientQuery\",\"status\":\"success\",\"cubeName\":\"Hourly Targets Operations by Model\",\"cubeID\":\"aHourlyIAAaTargetsIAAaOperationsIAAabyIAAaModel\",\"startQueryTimeStamp\":\"2016-02-15T02:14:23+00:00\",\"endQueryTimeStamp\":\"2016-02-15T02:14:23+00:00\",\"queryResponeLengthBytes\":0,\"duration\":0,\"concurrentQuery\":14,\"action\":\"finishQueryJaql\",\"@timestamp\":\"2016-02-15T02:14:23.253Z\",\"appTypeName\":\"dataserver\",\"@version\":\"1\",\"host\":\"VDED12270\",\"type\":\"productLogs\",\"tags\":[],\"send_type\":\"PullGen1\",\"sisenseuid\":\"janos.kopecek@regenersis.com\",\"sisenseOwnerid\":\"janos.kopecek@regenersis.com\",\"sisenseVersion\":\" 5.8.1.29\",\"sisenseMonitoringVersion\":\"3.0.0.6\",\"inputType\":\"sqs\",\"token\":\"fTdyoSwaFZTalBlnFIlTsqvvzfKZVGle\",\"logstash_host\":\"vpc_cluster_1\"}}"
>
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an handler function and specify which elements you need:

```
stream_in(url(url) , handler = function(x) x$"_source$duration")
```

Comment: can the handler do both rows subset and columns subset ? if so how you recommend doing that ?